# CakePHP Auth Component validation issue

Tags: authentication, cakephp, validation

Have some validating problems which seem to appear only when using the Auth component.
I have 4 fields in my register form: `username`, `password`, `password_confirm` and `email`.

I also have the multivalidatable behaviour attached to my User model. Here are the rules which apply to the register form:

```
var $validationSets=array(
    "register" => array(
        "username" => array(
            "usernameFieldNotEmpty" => array(
                "rule" => "notEmpty",
                "message" => "You did not enter the username!"
            ),
            "usernameValid" => array(
                "rule" => "__alphaNumericDashUnderscore",
                "message" => "The username you entered is not valid!"
            ),
            "usernameExistsInDatabase" => array(
                "rule" => array("__existingRecord", false), 
                "message" => "The username you entered has been already registered in our database!"
            )
        ),
        "password" => array(
            "passwordFieldNotEmpty" => array(
                "rule" => "notEmpty",
                "message" => "You did not enter your password!"
            )
        ),
        "password_confirm" => array(
            "passwordConfirmFieldNotEmpty" => array(
                "rule" => "notEmpty",
                "message" => "You did not confirm your password!"
            ),
            "passwordsMatch" => array(
                "rule" => array("__fieldMatch", "password"),
                "message" => "The passwords you entered don't match!"
            )
        ),
        "email" => array(
            "emailFieldNotEmpty" => array(
                "rule" => "notEmpty",
                "message" => "You did not enter the e-mail!"
            ),
            "emailValid" => array(
                "rule" => "email",
                "message" => "The e-mail you entered is not valid!"
            ),
            "emailExistsInDatabase" => array(
                "rule" => array("__existingRecord", false), 
                "message" => "The e-mail you entered has been already registered in our database!"
            )
        )
        /*"language" => array(

        )*/
    )
```

Here is my register form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'register')));?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php __('Add User'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password', array('type' => 'password', 'value' => ''));//value='' - resets the password input on any error on the page
    echo $this->Form->input('password_confirm', array('type' => 'password', 'value' => ''));
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
```

Now, everytime I submit the form EMPTY, the password field, although empty, passes all validation tests (I tried putting `value => ''` in the code, but it's useless).
Also, the email input seems to pass the `'notEmpty'` test and the error shown is that `The email is not valid`

I've looked over all my code but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: how are you checking the passwords against each other ?

Comment: a password field used with auth will never be empty, all you want to do is check that the compare_pw field is valid and that the hashed version matches the password field. you are correct in saying that your solution is a hack. you can compare then like return Security::hash($this->data['User']['compare'], null, true) === $this->data['User']['password'];

Comment: This is what I've done. Actually, my problem lied within the controller, of how can I 'reset' the password field. I figured it out in the 'edit' below. But instead of Security::hash(), I've used $this->Auth->password() to be in tone with the Auth component... :) Also, an important notice is that the `password` field will be hashed ONLY when you also have a `username` field in the form. Otherwise it'll will remain plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do a couple of "hacks" so the problem is solved for now.
Don't think this is the most appropriate way of doing it, but it might get in handy for other users having my problem:

Firstly, in my UsersController, I wrote this snippet, so if the password field is left empty by the user, reset it to `''` before validation:

```
if($this->data['User']['password'] == $this->Auth->password('')){
            $this->data['User']['password'] = '';
        }
        $this->User->set($this->data);
        if($this->User->validates()){ //post validation login }
```

The second problem was the e-mail validation. Oddly, I got this problem fixed by **changing** the order of the rules in the Multivalidatable Behaviour. So, from:

```
"email" => array(
        "emailFieldNotEmpty" => array(
            "rule" => "notEmpty",
            "message" => "You did not enter the e-mail!"
        ),
        "emailValid" => array(
            "rule" => "email",
            "message" => "The e-mail you entered is not valid!"
        ),
        "emailExistsInDatabase" => array(
            "rule" => array("__existingRecord", false), 
            "message" => "The e-mail you entered has been already registered in our database!"
        )
    )
```

I now have:

```
"email" => array(
            "emailExistsInDatabase" => array(
                "rule" => array("__existingRecord", false), 
                "message" => "The e-mail you entered has been already registered in our database!"
            ),
            "emailValid" => array(
                "rule" => "email",
                "message" => "The e-mail you entered is not valid!"
            ),
            "emailFieldNotEmpty" => array(
                "rule" => "notEmpty",
                "message" => "You did not enter the e-mail!"
            )
        )
```

I don't know whether this was intended or not, but it seems like the **last** rule which isn't fulfilled is the one displayed. To my logic, the rules would have been arranged in their order of appearance, so if the first one doesn't apply, stop checking and display it.

I repeat, I don't know if this is the right approach, but I seem to have worked out these problems.

If you have anything to add up, please do so!

**EDIT**
Found the 'official' explanation in the Cake 1.3 Book. It says:

```
By default CakePHP tries to validate a field using all the validation rules declared for it and returns the error message for the last failing rule. But if the key last is set to true for a rule and it fails, then the error message for that rule is returned and further rules are not validated. So if you prefer to show the error message for the first failing rule then set 'last' => true for each rule.
```

So, another approach to my problem is to set the validation rules in their order of appearance and add a `last` key to the rule array.

Comment: I would recommend using the built in isUnique rule for the emailExistsInDatabase validation rule.

Comment: I wonder why that hasn't come across my mind...Thanks! (+1 for useful suggestion)

Comment: also instead of calling set, and then validates and then save, just call save() like if($this->Model->save($this->data)){//yes} else{//no}

Comment: That is what I did in first instance, but I thought it would be useful to let a door open for any other output message on the 'else' branch...

Answer (score 0):

http://pastebin.com/xnQ02BCW

this is what i would use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it isn't quite what I was looking for. The validation rules are all well-written, as they all work correctly when I disable the Auth component. The main problem is that the password field has always a value, even when I leave it empty. And also, the email validation doesn't seem to work quite right: it passes the notEmpty condition even when I leave it blank. Hope you now understood better what are my problems :)

Comment: yes. i got the point. before validation the Auth Comp hashes the password even if its empty. i had read about this some place. will try to dig it up how to get over it.

Comment: I'm looking forward to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: i tried to ask around in the irc. they asked to use the confirm password as a field. i think one way around is. since the hash of an empty password is always constant. why not add another rule not  equalTo the hash..

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried something like what you've mentioned (written the answer below) and it works, even though it isn't quite the most practical solution...

Comment: will post back if i come across any answer :D

Answer (score 0):

About the Password problem: what version of CakePHP are you using?

The Auth component in 1.2 automatically hash your password, so that it will result not empty even if it is. In 1.3 it should be OK but I don't know from what version.

Comment: I'm using 1.3 and it still hashes it. I've put the `value=''` in the view, which sorts out the field, but the validation still passes, even though I left the field empty.